# A probability issue with two urns having the same size of balls

Tags: probability, distributions, self-study

In Urn No. 1 (first urn) there are $y$ balls, of which $x$ white balls and $y-x$ black balls. In Urn No. 2 (second first) there are $y$ balls again, but the white balls are $y-x$. You randomly take a ball from the first urn and place it in the second urn. Then, from the second urn you randomly take a ball and place it in the first urn.

Calculate the probability distribution of $A_r$ = "in the first urn there are at the end $r$ white balls".

Do you have any advice? I was thinking of applying the binomial distribution, but I would not be sure to proceed.

I thank anyone who can help me.

Comment: There are only four possibilities: you can easily work out their chances case by case.

Comment: @whuber because they are Bernoullian trials with $2^n = 2^2 = 4$ where $n$ they are the number of urns. Right?

Comment: That's not really the reason.  The reason is that there are two possible outcomes for the first draw and, for each of them, two possible outcomes for the second draw.  $2\times 2=4$ is the reason.